# Intersection (set theory) how to write as a logical statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am having troubles writing down the definition of the intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$ (that is not empty). 
I thought of

$$(∃x)(∃y)(x∈A∧y∈B∧x=y)\enspace\text{or} \enspace(∃x)(∃y)((x∈A∧y∈B)⇒x=y)$$

but I am not sure, which of them, if any, is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: The second one will not do anything useful -- it is always true no matter what $A$ and $B$ are, because you can choose $x$ and $y$ to be outside both sets and thereby make the implication true. (Writing $\Rightarrow$ under an $\exists$ is almost always a mistake).

Answer (score 2):

I guess, "definition" means that you should build a set, e.g.
$$
C = A \cap B
$$
means
$$
\forall x: (x \in C) \leftrightarrow ((x\in A) \wedge (x \in B))
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\exists x[x\in A\wedge x\in B]$$ expresses that the intersection $A\cap B$ is not empty.

Is that what you are after?

Further if $A$ and $B$ are two sets then $$A\cap B:=\{x\in A\mid x\in B\}$$

Answer (score 0):

A $\cap$ B = { x| x $\in$ A and x $\in$ B}

A $\cap$ B is the set that contains all x that belongs to both A and B i.e it contains all elements common to A and B.